# How to defend own computer from bitcoin mining soft?

Tags: 14.04, antivirus

I have noticed that my computer became slower, and I suspect that it's because of bitcoin mining software, because my battery also empties fast.

Here is result of: `$ top`:
[image]

How can I check and eventually remove this software?

Comment: It's probably not. Is `top` showing any CPU-hogging applications?

Comment: Nothing there shows any significant CPU use, so I highly doubt you have a miner installed...

Comment: I have not installed miners I thought I've got it from Internet. It seems like chrome takes more memory. Thanks

Comment: But not abnormal amounts. In short, there's no reason, based on the information you have given, to believe you have malware.

Comment: @vidarlo thanks for your consultation. I am going to close question